# ER diagram, entity identified be one attribute OR another attribute

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-relationship

I was just wondering how the following would be represented in an ER diagram.

**Question**

Each person is identified by a unique id number **OR** their full name, which includes first name, middle name, and last name.

This is what I have done so far. This is probably a very easy question, but I am new to database design and any help would be mush appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Person needs a unique identifier/primary key, whether it is a surrogate, or an ugly concat of ID_FullName.  You can keep both and mark them unique (nullable) if there are cases where one is null.

If you really need both then rethink whether you need a supertype like Entity with subTypes of Person and UnamedPerson -- you have to ask yourself why there wouldn't be a UniqueID in all cases for a Person and decide there.

Also consider a more compact representation for ERD's -- there are alot of variants, but most look like this w/ Crows feet as my pref.

[image: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/data-modeling/what-is-entity-relationship-diagram/]

Also look for sample ERD's similar to your use case to model off.  Person/Entity/Group/Role stuff has common idioms.